# How do I set a variable `true` when updating the database has been successful?

Tags: php, mysql, methods, boolean

On a blog I'm coding the admin can give an 'author'-permission to users.

When the update of the db table has been successful and their permission has been set to 'author' the admin will be headed back to the list of all current authors.

I want a message("Author has been added." for e.g) to appear on this site when it has been successful.

Of course the possibility of the db-update not working is minimal I think, but I want this case to be considered.

To do this I wanted to set a `$newAuthor` `true` when the database has been updated, but it didn't worked trying it with an `if`.

Here are the functions in the AdminController and the UserRepository with the db query:

```
//AdminController
public function permissionAuthor()
{
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $permission = "author";
  $newAuthor = false;
  if($this->userRepository->changePermission($id, $permission)) {
    $newAuthor = true;
  }
  header("Location: authors");
}

//UserRepository
public function changePermission($id, $permission)
{
  $table = $this->getTableName();

  $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare(
    "UPDATE `{$table}` SET `permission` = :permission WHERE `id` = :id");
  $changedPermission = $stmt->execute([
    'id' => $id,
    'permission' => $permission
  ]);
  return $changedPermission;
}

// authors.php / the view
<?php if(isset($newAuthor) && $newAuthor == true):?>
  <p class="error">Author has been added.</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

How can I achieve that `$newAuthor` will only be set to `true` when the function that updates the database has been successful and the message to be displayed in the view?

**EDIT**

I tried it with returning `$changedPermission` in the `UserRepository`. It might be wrong because it hasn't changed anything.

Comment: You could set a session variable $_SESSION['newauthor']=true in the permissionAuthor function

Comment: `changePermission()` doesn't return anything to say if it has worked or not.  You could either return that `execute()` has worked or check [`rowCount`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) (although this will only be set if the permissions change).

Comment: Also not sure how `$newAuthor` is going to be passed to the authors.php page.

Comment: Update statements don't return a correct value for `rowCount()` unless the row was actually changed. So in the case where the user already has author permissions and you try to give it to them again, you will run into problems. That's why I verify that update statements work by querying the database for that row after i do the update. Something like `"select count(*)  from {$table} where permission = :permission and id = :id"`

Comment: @bassxzero It's not possible to give the 'author' permission again when the user already has it, I considered that case

Comment: Also directly put $newAuthor = $this->userRepository->changePermission($id, $permission); in permissionAuthor function.
But one more thing, I don't see where you are calling your permissionAuthor function in your code ? Are you sure it's executed ?

Answer (score -2):

You can either check the permission before changing it and see if there's a difference, or just check if the UPDATE request worked successfully.

Since the prototype: `public PDOStatement::execute ([ array $input_parameters ] ) : bool`

You can check if the request has been successful by verifying the return value of the execute function like that:

```
$result = $stmt->execute([
    'id' => $id,
    'permission' => $permission
  ]);

if ($result == FALSE)
    echo 'ERROR';
else
    echo 'ok';
```

Also directly put `$newAuthor = $this->userRepository->changePermission($id, $permission);` in permissionAuthor function.

But one more thing, I don't see where you are calling your permissionAuthor function in your code ? Are you sure it's executed ?

Comment: This belongs in the comments section of the post, not as an "answer." Answers should show the work.

Comment: the second one was my thought, but I don't know how I achieve that, I'm quite new to php

Comment: I can't add comments I have not enough reputation.. lol And I'm going to add the solution to check if the request was successful

Comment: @MathieuGasciolli Not having enough reputation isn't a good reason to circumvent the commenting restriction by posting a comment as an answer; in fact, it's a good way to _lose_ reputation

Comment: I did it with routes, the permissionAuthor() method will be executed when there's a specific url (when clicking an input type="submit" it will link to this url

Comment: maybe you need to add global in the declaration of $newAuthor to access it from everywhere